# Getting an error while trying to apply gradients with respect to input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using StyleGANv2 (https://github.com/moono/stylegan2-tf-2.x) with original weights.
My TF version is 2.2.0. The default training process and inference work fine.

But I'm trying to do learning steps with respect to input:

```
rnd = np.random.RandomState(seed)
latents = rnd.randn(1, generator.z_dim).astype(np.float32)
labels = rnd.randn(1, generator.labels_dim).astype(np.float32)

initial_input = [tf.convert_to_tensor(latents), tf.convert_to_tensor(labels)]
input_tensor = tf.Variable([initial_input[0]])

for step in range(10):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        tape.watch(initial_input[0])
        if step == 0:
            generated_image = generator(initial_input)
        else:
            generated_image = generator([input_tensor[0,:,:], initial_input[1]])
        
        # target_image - the image I'm trying to learn latents for
        loss_value = mae_loss(generated_image, target_image)
        
    plt.imshow(postprocess_images(generated_image).numpy()[0])
    plt.show()
    
    print("Loss: ", loss_value)
    print("Tensor: ", input_tensor)
    print("Initial Input: ", [initial_input[0]])
    
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, [initial_input[0]])

    print("Gradients: ", gradients)
    
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([gradients], [input_tensor]))
```

The first step completes successfully, but on the second step I'm getting an error:
`ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.`

And `gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, [initial_input[0]])` returns `None` on the second step.

So any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: This could interest you : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#getting_a_gradient_of_none
Also, I don't understand why you create a tf.Variable in the GradientTape scope.

Comment: Because there are no dependencies from `loss_value` to `initial_input[0]` when `step>0`. `input_tensor` is not the same as `initial_input[0]` for graph, because `input_tensor` is the other `tf.Variable` initialized by `initial_input[0]` as initial values.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The problem is that Tensor objects are not mutable in TensorFlow, thus the optimizer cannot apply gradients to it (look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166864/tensorflow-python-framework-ops-eagertensor-object-has-no-attribute-in-graph). So, I need to create Variable. But I also need Tensor object to feed generator. So, I don't know, how to do it properly.

Comment: Create buffer=tf.Variable before all calculations, then update buffer values with values from input. tf.Variable should be created only once for graph as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. Thanks to @klapeyron. I updated tf.Variable values with values from input_tensor:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

initial_input = [tf.convert_to_tensor(latents), tf.convert_to_tensor(labels)]
input_tensor = tf.Variable([initial_input[0]])

for step in range(100):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(initial_input[0])

        initial_input[0] = input_tensor[0,:,:]
        generated_image = generator(initial_input)initial_input[1]])
        
        loss_value = mse_loss(generated_image, target_image)
        
    plt.imshow(postprocess_images(generated_image).numpy()[0])
    plt.show()
    
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, [initial_input[0]])
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([gradients], [input_tensor]))
```